# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated (on click of logout)

Tags: vaadin

I am facing following exception once I click on logout button -
`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.getAttribute(StandardSession.java:1148) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.getAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:102) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.WrappedHttpSession.getAttribute(WrappedHttpSession.java:54) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.security.VaadinAwareSecurityContextHolderStrategy.getFromVaadinSession(VaadinAwareSecurityContextHolderStrategy.java:71) ~[vaadin-spring-23.2.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.security.VaadinAwareSecurityContextHolderStrategy.getContext(VaadinAwareSecurityContextHolderStrategy.java:56) ~[vaadin-spring-23.2.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.getContext(SecurityContextHolder.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler.logout(SecurityContextLogoutHandler.java:71) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at com.example.application.security.SecurityService.logout(SecurityService.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.application.views.main.MainView.lambda$new$bd3514ab$1(MainView.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:233) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:475) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:292) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:447) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:447) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:62) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:75) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:438) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:419) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:419) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:320) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:115) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1564) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:369) ~[flow-server-23.2.5.jar:23.2.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:106) ~[vaadin-spring-23.2.5.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

`

Here is the security service -

```
@Component
public class SecurityService {
    public void logout() {
        UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("/");
        SecurityContextLogoutHandler securityContextLogoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
        securityContextLogoutHandler.logout(VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent().getHttpServletRequest(), null, null);
    }
}
```

Here is the Security configuration -

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    private static class CrmInMemoryUserDetailsManager extends InMemoryUserDetailsManager {
        public CrmInMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
            createUser(new User("user",
                    "{noop}userpass",
                    Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(USER_ROLE))));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Authorize access to /images/ without authentication
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/icons/**").permitAll();
        // Set default security policy that permits Vaadin internal requests and
        // denies all other
        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        return new CrmInMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    }
}
```

This is the main view class which has the logout button -

```
@PageTitle("Main")
@Route(value = "")
@RolesAllowed(value = {USER_ROLE})
public class MainView extends HorizontalLayout {

    private TextField name;
    private Button sayHello;

    private SecurityService securityService;

    public MainView(SecurityService securityService) {
        this.securityService = securityService;

        name = new TextField("Your name");
        sayHello = new Button("Say hello");
        sayHello.addClickListener(e -> {
            Notification.show("Hello " + name.getValue());
        });
        sayHello.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);

        Button logOut = new Button("Log Out", e -> securityService.logout());

        setMargin(true);
        setVerticalComponentAlignment(Alignment.END, name, sayHello);

        add(name, sayHello, logOut);
    }

}
```

I am not sure why the session is getting invalidated or how I can improve it. Please help me understand/resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/14950) to be fixed in the next version. Workaround downgrade to 23.2.5 or use your own code to logout.